# How do you guys sync FE data models with BE data models

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a Typescript application. We often add interfaces for API responses, but BE sometimes forgot to inform us API response changes. Or, new hires just don't know they need to tell us. When stuff isn't automated, we'll forget from time to time. How do you guys validate the FE data models align with BE data models?

Comment: You can use the same files for BE and FE or you can let the files for the FE be generated by the BE.

Comment: This seems to be more of a [softwareengineering.se] question. Voting to close as off-topic.